# Zend Framework, passing variables to view

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a problem with displaying a view. When I pass var to view, view doesn't render.

Controller:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $branchModel = new Application_Model_Branches();
    $branches = $branchModel->getAllBranches();
    $this->view->menu = $branches;
}
```

View (index.phtml):

```
<h2>Menu</h2>
<?php
    $this->htmlList($this->menu);
?>
```

When I try debug `$branches` without assign it to view, all seems to be ok, but when I try push it to view,index.phtml don't appear.

Regards

Comment: The code you have looks fine. If you var_dump($this->menu) in your index.phtml, does that work?

Answer (score 14):

You're just missing an echo in your code, the `htmlList` view helper returns a value - it doesn't echo it. Some examples of the various form view helpers can be seen [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html)

```
<h2>Menu</h2>
<?php
    echo $this->htmlList($this->menu);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

**controller**

```
    $this->view->variableName = "Hello World!";//assign here        

    $this->view->assign('variableName1', "Hello new World!");//assign here
```

**view**

```
    echo $this->variableName;//echo here

    echo $this->variableName1;//echo here
```