# How to use this php code in zend framework 1.12

Tags: php, zend-framework

I need the ability to enter an IP address in a form and then that IP would be used to obtain a status.php page that is running on http://'IP':port/status.php and then display the contents below the form.

I attached the two index.php and status.php files I have. They work outside of zend.

How would I do this with zend 1.12 ?

status.php

```
<?php

/*error_log(date("U").": ".implode(", ",array_keys(($_REQUEST)))."\n",3,"/tmp/phperror.log");
if(!isset($_REQUEST['ip']))
exit(0);
*/
$ip = $_POST['IP'];


function getIP($ip)
{
    $port = ( $_REQUEST[ 'port' ] != "" ? $_REQUEST[ 'port' ] : '1234' );
    $site='http://'.$ip.':'.$port.'/status.php';
    //foreach( $_REQUEST as $k => $v)
    if ( $_REQUEST[ 'mode' ] != 'json' ) {
        //error_log(date("U").": ".$site." : ".implode($_REQUEST)."\n",3,"/tmp/phperror.log");
        error_log( date( "U" ) . ": " . $site . " : " . implode( ", ", array_keys( ( $_REQUEST ) ) ) . "\n", 3, "/tmp/phperror.log" );
        $file = file_get_contents( $site, false, $context );
        echo $file;
    }
    else {
        if ( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_METHOD' ] == 'POST' ) {
            $r    = $site . "?d=v";
            $data = array();
            foreach ( $_REQUEST as $key => $value ) {
                $r .= "&$key=$value";
                $data[ $key ] = $value;
            }
            $options = array( 'http' => array(
                'method'  => 'POST',
                'content' => http_build_query( $data )
            ) );
            error_log( date( "U" ) . ": " . $r . "\n", 3, "/tmp/phperror.log" );
            $context = stream_context_create( $options );
            //$file = file_get_contents($r, false, $context);
            $file = file_get_contents( $site, false, $context );
            echo $file;
        }
    }
}

getIP($ip);
?>
```

index. php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name=description content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                <h1 class="text-center">IP Address</h1>
                <form action="status.php" method="post" role="form" class="form-horizontal">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="IP" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Enter IP Address</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="IP" id="IP" placeholder="IP Address">
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="deleteFile()">Submit</button>
                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger">Clear</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div id="section"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        /* Deletes the selected file */
        function deleteFile() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "status.php",
                data: {
                    IP: $( "#IP" ).val()
                }
            })
                .success(function (data) {
                    $('#section').html(data);
                });
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

**EDIT:**

I followed Lucian's steps and I believe I do not have my indexaction on the controller correct.

I pasted status.php there and its erroring.... What do I have wrong

indexcontroller.php

```
<?php

class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

public function init()
{
    /* Initialize action controller here */
}

public function indexAction()
{


/*error_log(date("U").": ".implode(", ",array_keys(($_REQUEST)))."\n",3,"/tmp/phperror.log");
if(!isset($_REQUEST['ip']))
exit(0);
*/
$ip = $_POST['IP'];


function getIP($ip)
{
    $port = ( $_REQUEST[ 'port' ] != "" ? $_REQUEST[ 'port' ] : '1234' );
    $site='http://'.$ip.':'.$port.'/status.php';
    //foreach( $_REQUEST as $k => $v)
    if ( $_REQUEST[ 'mode' ] != 'json' ) {
        //error_log(date("U").": ".$site." : ".implode($_REQUEST)."\n",3,"/tmp/phperror.log");
        error_log( date( "U" ) . ": " . $site . " : " . implode( ", ", array_keys( ( $_REQUEST ) ) ) . "\n", 3, "/tmp/phperror.log" );
        $file = file_get_contents( $site, false, $context );
        echo $file;
    }
    else {
        if ( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_METHOD' ] == 'POST' ) {
            $r    = $site . "?d=v";
            $data = array();
            foreach ( $_REQUEST as $key => $value ) {
                $r .= "&$key=$value";
                $data[ $key ] = $value;
            }
            $options = array( 'http' => array(
                'method'  => 'POST',
                'content' => http_build_query( $data )
            ) );
            error_log( date( "U" ) . ": " . $r . "\n", 3, "/tmp/phperror.log" );
            $context = stream_context_create( $options );
            //$file = file_get_contents($r, false, $context);
            $file = file_get_contents( $site, false, $context );
            echo $file;
        }
    }
}

getIP($ip);
    ?>

}
```

Comment: And whats wrong with Zend?

Comment: what leads you to think it won't work in zend?

Comment: I never worked with it before so I do not know what I would add to what and what syntax to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all create a layout (layout.phtml) using the html content of your index.php that is static and gets repeated on every page.

Second create a controller and put the php from the status.php inside an action within the controller.

Third create a corresponding view to the controller and echo out everything that is computed in the action of the controller.

Fourth create a Zend Form for the html form...

You could do a lot more, but i would adivse you to start with the basics (Step 1 - 3).
For more information on view / controller / action in zend, have a look at:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/de/zend.controller.action.html

**EDIT:**

There are some quick start skeletons that can help you to jumpstart your application. Have a look at

https://github.com/RichardKnop/zend-v112-skeleton

You will find the mentioned stuff like "controller","action","view" among the files / folders inside the skeleton, just customize them to your needs.

**EDIT 2**

You can pass data from the controller to the view using **$this->view** from the controller.
For that checkout this answer on stackoverflow:
[Zend Framework, passing variables to view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772138/zend-framework-passing-variables-to-view)

Comment: Can you expound on the 3rd step on how to "echo out everything that is computed" from my example code.

Comment: I completed the layout, pasted status.php code into indexaction for indexcontroller.php and setup the form.

So far I have an error
"( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /var/www/html/test/application/controllers/IndexController.php on line 60"

I don't know if this will clear with me "echo'ing out everything in view"

Comment: please post a new question for the further problems you have. try to setup a running page using ONLY the skeleton. when everything works without errors, start customizing the controller/view to your needs at a step by step basis, meaning change something & try immediatly if it works. think in small steps.